# BufferGeometry offsets and indices

Tags: javascript, three.js, indices, buffer-geometry

I was just wondering for a while now what exactly "offsets" and "indices / index" are. Offsets are e.g. mentioned in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/BufferGeometry.js and indices were mentioned in IndexedGeometry, however I can't currently find it anymore in the dev tree.
Although indices seem rather obvious and although I could dive into the code to figure out some maybe-correct answer for myself I'd love to hear an "official" statement :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to defining geometries:

**Non-Indexed**

```
"vertices": [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8,  ... ],
"normals":  [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8,  ... ]
```

In this mode every triangle position is as defined and you can't reuse data.

```
triangle 0: [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8 ]
```

**Indexed**

```
"indices":  [ 0, 1, 2, ... ],
"vertices": [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8,  ... ],
"normals":  [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8,  ... ]
```

In this mode, indices define the order of the data. The first triangle is using indices `0`, `1`, and `2`. These indices will be used to fetch the `vertices` and `normals` data:

```
triangle 0: [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8 ]
```

The main benefit of indexed is the possibility of reusing data and uploading less data to the GPU:

```
"indices":  [ 0, 0, 0, ... ],
"vertices": [ 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8,  ... ]

triangle 0: [ 0, 1, 2,  0, 1, 2,  0, 1, 2 ]
```

As per **offsets**...

With offsets you can render specific ranges of your geometry. Instead of drawing from `triangle 0` to `triangle.length`, you can draw from `triangle 200` to `triangle 400`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do the numbers make sense this way? Let's say we build a flat plane then the non-indexed would be [0,0,0, 0,1,0] [0,0,1, 0,0,1], right? Then how would/could the numbers look when indexed? (Could you maybe edit that into your post..?) Further can I define multiple offsets, e.g. to draw every second "line" of a plane?

Comment: @Doidel I tried to modify the answer using a simple plane geometry but I think it's more confusing.

Comment: @Doidel you can indeed draw multiple offsets but bear in mind that every offset is a draw call so you don't want to do a ton of those. It tends to be used for multi material stuff.